# How to loop through Subdirectories in linux and find files without ".csv" extension using perl on linux

Tags: perl, csv

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $dir = '/path/to/dir';
open( DIR, $dir ) or die $!;
while ( my $file = readdir(DIR) ) {
    next if ( $file =~ m/(^\.)/ );
    if ( $file !~ m/csv$/ ) {
        print "*** renaming file $file ***\n";
        $oldfile = $file;
        $file =~ s/\..*$/.csv/;
        print "$oldfile => $file\n";
        rename $oldfile, $file;
        print "Done\n";
    }
}
```

I have tried to perl -c to see if there were any syntax errors. I think i have a flaw in a logic somewhere somehow. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: And what's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: @Sobrique - script runs without any errors, but doesnt seem to be working at all. -vv doesnt throw anything either

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems

- You are using `open` to read the directory instead of `opendir`
- You are processing both files and directories that `readdir` returns
- You are renaming file names without a path, which means Perl will look in the current directory which probably isn't `/path/to/dir`

This will do what you intended

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = '/path/to/dir';

chdir $dir or die $!;
opendir my $dh, '.' or die $!;

while ( my $file = readdir $dh ) {

    next unless -f $file;
    next if $file =~ /\.csv\z/i;

    print "*** Renaming file $file ***\n";

    my $newfile = $file;
    $newfile =~ s/\.[^.]*\z//;
    $newfile .= '.csv';

    print "$file => $newfile\n";
    rename $file, $newfile or die $!;
    print "Done\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `open()` is used for files. What you want is `opendir()`. Next, when you use `opendir(), readdir()`, it doesn't keep the path information, so you need to prepend it to the files you're renaming. Third, it's more common to use lexical handles as opposed to bare names. Lastly, always `use strict;` and `use warnings;` which would have pointed you directly to the problem.

Here's a slightly updated version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir = "/path/to/dir";
opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die $!;

while ( my $file = readdir($dh) ) {
    next if ( $file =~ m/(^\.)/ );
    next unless -f $file;
    if ( $file !~ m/csv$/ ) {
        print "*** renaming file $file ***\n";
        my $oldfile = $file;
        $file =~ s/\..*$/.csv/;
        print "$oldfile => $file\n";
        rename "$dir/$oldfile", "$dir/$file";
        print "Done\n";
    }
}
```

Another way to do this is use a file glob (per suggestion by Sobrique):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = </path/to/dir/*>;

for my $file (@files){

    next unless -f $file;

    if ($file !~ /\.csv$/){
        print "*** renaming file $file ***\n";
        my $oldfile = $file;
        $file =~ s/\..*$/.csv/;
        print "$oldfile => $file\n";
        rename $oldfile, $file;
        print "Done!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would normally suggest glob

Comment: Updated with a similar example using glob

Comment: I would normally suggest glob \**/\*